# What causes this NameError: name 'ax' is not defined in my Googlecolab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

yes = data['converted'].value_counts()['yes']
no = data['converted'].value_counts()['no']
print(yes,'users converted to subscribers.')
print(no, 'users did not convert')

plt.figure(figsize=(12,7))
ax= ax_sns.countplot(data["converted"],palette='pink')

yes = data['converted'].value_counts()['yes']
no = data['converted'].value_counts()['no']
print(yes,'users converted to subscribers.')
print(no, 'users did not convert')

plt.figure(figsize=(12,7))
ax= ax_sns.countplot(data["converted"],palette='pink')

Was expecting countplot

Comment: Please take a moment to format your code, then ensure that you provide a reproducible example. Maybe post a link to your colab.